# Compartir objetos entre varias formas

Tags: c#

Hola tengo un problema cuando intento compartir objetos entre formas. Tengo un objeto `ConfData` en el que tengo varios atributos que quiero actualizar entre las diferentes formas que tengo. El código es el siguiente:

```
public partial class ConfigDataViewer : UserControl
{
    #region Atributos privados

    /// <summary>
    /// Creamos el objeto para asignar los valores de la interfaz a los datos internos
    /// </summary>
    ECCE_ConfigData ConfData = new ECCE_ConfigData();

    TcConfig oTcConfig = new TcConfig(ConfData); -> ERROR

    UvConfig oUvConfig = new UvConfig();

    #endregion Atributos privados
```

Este objeto ConfData lo paso a otra Form para que actualize una serie de valores y pueda obtenerlos desde este control. Este es el codigo de la otra forma

```
public partial class TcConfig : Form
{
    ECCE_ConfigData ConfData2 = new ECCE_ConfigData();
    AñadirTc oTc = new AñadirTc();
    int i = 0;

    public TcConfig(ECCE_ConfigData ConfData)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ConfData2 = ConfData;
    }

    public void buttonAñadirTc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (oTc.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ConfData2.TcCnf.TcCnfArray[i] = new sTcCnf(Convert.ToByte(oTc.textBox_IdTc.Text), Convert.ToByte(oTc.textBox_TcType.Text), Convert.ToByte(oTc.textBox_NumUVsTc.Text), Convert.ToByte(oTc.textBox_NumUVsNormalizacion.Text), Convert.ToByte(oTc.textBox_IdUVNormalizacion.Text), Convert.ToByte(oTc.textBox_TcParamFlags.Text));
            i++;
         }
     }
```

Este último código es correcto. El problema es que la clase del objeto `ConfData` no es estática y el error que me pone en la línea que he puesto `ERROR` es:

> Error 1   Un inicializador de campo no puede hacer referencia al campo,
>   método o propiedad no estáticos
>   'CSCI_ECCE_APP.UserControls.ConfigDataViewer.ConfData'

Alguien sabe como puedo resolver esto? He intentado hacer estática la clase del objeto ConfData pero me da muchisimos errores y prefiero otra solución.
Gracias

Comment: De todas maneras, el error diría que es por intentar instanciar desde la definición del campo. Intenta dejar la definición asi `TcConfig oTcConfig;` y luego en el constructor de `ConfigDataViewer` inicializalo `oTcConfig = new TcConfig(ConfData);`

Comment: has definido como partial la clase por algo???

Comment: lo de partial se me pone solo. Ahora probare eso Pikoh. Instancio TcConfig porque después accedo a los text boxes, etc desde esta clase

Comment: Así es @Pikoh si defino las variables fuera del constructor y las inicializo dentro se me va el error (aunque no acabo de entender el porque ese error). Muchas gracias!

Comment: Xim, mira mi respuesta para una explicación de porque se produce ese error. Un saludo

Answer (score 0):

Ese error se produce por intentar usar un campo de instancia para inicializar otro campo de instancia. La solución es inicializar los campos dentro del constructor de la clase. En tu caso,define los campos sin inicializar:

```
TcConfig oTcConfig;
```

Y luego inicializales en el constructor:

```
oTcConfig = new TcConfig(ConfData);
```

En la página de MSDN [Error del compilador CS0236](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0236) pone un ejemplo simplificado del problema:

```
public class MiClase
{  
    public int i = 5;  
    public int j = i;  // Error
}
```

Una posible explicación es la siguiente. El compilador, en ocasiones, por cuestiones de optimización o de otro tipo, podría cambiar el orden de las definiciones. En ese caso, usando el ejemplo, `int j` se intentaría inicializar antes de `int i`, lo que obviamente provocaría un error al no estar `i` aun definida. Así que la solución de microsoft es no permitir este tipo de definiciones directamente.

Comment: Gracias!!      @Pikoh